# Deprecation warning while generating word-cloud

Tags: python, word-cloud, python-3.10, deprecation-warning

When trying to generate a word cloud in Python 3.10. I get a deprecation warning stating that:
08: DeprecationWarning: textsize is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use textbbox or textlength instead.

I used to run the same code with Python 3.7 without any warning. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?
I get a very long list of this warning repeatedly in my notebook. I am looking for a way to fix this warning.

Here is the code I am using:

```
def wordcloud(self) -> None:
    """Function to generate wordcloud"""
    long_string = ','.join(self.corpus)
    # Create a WordCloud object
    wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white",
                          max_words=5000,
                          contour_width=3,
                          contour_color='steelblue')
    # Generate a word cloud
    wordcloud.generate(long_string)
    # Visualize the word cloud
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of WordCloud?

Comment: I am using version: 1.8.2.2

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/690

Comment: Don't worry about it. As long as you don't upgrade Pillow before WordCloud is fixed, it shouldn't be a problem.